# Elixir binary matching combine 'bytes' & 'integer'

Tags: parsing, pattern-matching, elixir

### Problem

I want to make a custom file packer written in Elixir but I've a problem.
I have to match a number with a size in bytes. For example:

```
iex(1)> << value :: little-???-size(4), _ :: binary >> = << 1, 0, 0, 0, 255 >>
<< 1, 0, 0, 0, 255 >>
iex(2)> value
1
```

I know I can use `little-size(32)` but the size is in bits. I can use `bytes-size(4)` but I get `<< 1, 0, 0, 0 >>`. Maybe is there any way to combine them ?

---

### Files

My files are following this syntax:

```
> 4 bytes: number of files

// First file
> 4 bytes: sub-file's name length
> X bytes: sub-file's name
> 4 bytes: sub-file's content length
> X bytes: sub-file's content

// Second file
> 4 bytes: sub-file's name length
> ...
```

---

### Goal

I just want to combine the following code into **only one pattern matching**:

```
# Get name length
<<
    name_length :: bytes-size(4),
    rest :: binary
>> = data

name_bytes = name_length * 8

# Get Filename, and buffer size
<<
    filename :: size(name_bytes),
    buffer_size :: bytes-size(4),
    rest :: binary
>> = rest

buffer_bytes = buffer_size * 8

# Get buffer
<<
    buffer :: size(buffer_bytes),
    rest :: binary
>> = rest
```

Comment: I think you've overtagged this question.  I'm removing the functional-programming tag because there's nothing about your question which is specific to FP. The parsing and pattern-matching tags are also a little suspect but I'll leave them in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer. If some people have the same problem than me, use `binary-size(size_in_byte)` (for more information about the binary type, just put `h <<>>` into your iex console).

---

### Example:

```
iex(1)> <<
...         name_length :: little-size(32),
...         filename :: binary-size(name_length),
...         buffer_size :: little-size(32),
...         buffer :: binary-size(buffer_size),
...         rest :: binary
...     >> = data
[ ... some data ... ]
iex(2)> name_length
8
iex(3)> filename
"Toto.txt"
```

---

### Explanation:

From iex doc:

```
[...]

### Unit and Size

The length of the match is equal to the `unit` (a number of bits) times the `size` (the number of repeated segments of length `unit`).

Type      | Default Unit
--------- | ------------
`integer` | 1 bit
`float`   | 1 bit
`binary`  | 8 bits

[...]

For binaries, the default is the size of the binary. Only the last binary in a match can use the default size. All others must have their size specified explicitly, even if the match is unambiguous. For example:

iex> <<name::binary-size(5), " the ", species::binary>> = <<"Frank the Walrus">>
"Frank the Walrus"
iex> {name, species}
{"Frank", "Walrus"}
```